# Form alerts for multipe inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, alert

I have the following code, and need to get an alert that will specify which fields are empty or null, and return an alert for each empty or null field. I'm new to JavaScript and struggling a great deal with this. Can anyone give me some advice on this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
    function checkForm(form){
        var len = form.length;

        //create for loop
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            if (form.elements[i].type=="text" || form.elements[i].type==null){
                if (form.fax number.value=="" || form.fax number.type==null){
                    alert("Please fill out the fax number field");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function emailTest(emailText){
        var email = emailText.value;
        var emailPattern = /^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
        if (!(emailPattern.test(email))) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            document.myForm[1].focus();
        }
    }
// -->
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H3>Assignment 2 Form</H3>
<HR>

<FORM NAME="myForm" METHOD="post"
ACTION="mailto:joeschmoe@blahblah.ca">
    Name:<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="name"><br>
    Email address:<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="email address" onBlur="emailTest(this);"><br>
    Phone number:<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="phone number"><br>
    Fax number:<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="fax number"><p>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit Data" onClick="return checkForm(this.form);">
    <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset Form">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `form.fax number` is invalid syntax(you cannot have a space in an identifier), use `form['fax number']`

Comment: And you don't need to have the `language` attribute in your `script` tags. That's severely outdated. Instead use `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: From what resource did you learn JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Ok...wow. I spent way too much time on this.
Your form should look like the following:

```
<FORM NAME="myForm" id="myForm">
<label for="name">Name:</label><br />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="name" /><br />
<label for="email_address">Email address:</label><BR />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="email_address" /><br />
<label for="phone_number">Phone number:</label><BR /> 
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="phone_number" /><br />
<label for="fax_number">Fax number:</label><BR />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" size="30" NAME="fax_number" /><br />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Submit Data" onClick="return checkForm()" />
    <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset Form" />
</FORM>
```

#### Form Summary:

- You should utilize labels for form elements
- Never use spaces for the name attribute or any identifying attribute for that matter (name, class, id)
- `input`s should end with `/>` as should any tag without an end tag (`<br />` too)
- I pulled out the `onBlur` event and just added it as a piece of the overall validation process. No need to make it too complicated
- I used a `button` input type instead of a `submit` input type. See why in the JavaScript

And then your JavaScript:

```
function checkForm() {
    var valid = false; //Set a boolean variable that will be changed on each block 
                       //of validation
    if (document.myForm.fax_number.value === "") {
        alert("Please fill out the fax number field");
    }

    if (document.myForm.email_address.value === "") {
        alert("Email address is required");
    } else {
        valid = emailTest(document.myForm.email_address.value);
    }

    //all other checks within if statements

    if (valid) {
        document.myForm.action = "mailto:soandso@so.com";
        document.myForm.submit();
    }
}

function emailTest(emailText) {
    var emailPattern = /^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
    var ret = false;
    if (!(emailPattern.test(emailText))) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
    } else {
        ret = true;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

#### Javascript Summary

- In JavaScript interacting with HTML forms, forms are called as such: `document.formName` where `formName` is the string in the `name=""` attribute of the form tag or `document.forms[i]` where `i` is the numerical instance of the form on the page, i.e. the first form on the page is `i = 0`, thus it would be called as `document.forms[0]`
- Check each `input` by `name` for a `value` with `document.myForm.(elementName).value` where `elementName` is the string from your `<input>`s `name` attribute.
- Instead of using a `submit`, I used a regular `button`. When the "Submit Data" button is clicked in the form, it runs `checkForm()` which makes sure everything is valid
- If everything is valid, it assigns an action to the form with `document.myForm.action=youraction` and then submits it via JavaScript with `document.myForm.submit()`

#### Notes

- Don't use [W3Schools](http://w3fools.com) to learn about anything ever.
- Read more about forms [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html)